# Using Flexbox to Ungroup Sidebar Elements on Narrow Displays

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is the layout behavior that I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Layouts]

The only way I can think of getting the wide display version to work is if I put the red and yellow boxes in a div, but then I can't get the narrow display version to work because `order` couldn't be used to move just the yellow box to be positioned after the blue box. What can I do to get this layout to work?

Comment: I love flexbox, but you may be better off just using media query break points for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using floats for desktop and switching to flex with `order` for mobile (click the "Full page" link after clicking "Run code snippet" to see the desktop version):

```css
/* floats for desktop */
.sidebar {
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  width: 250px;
}
.blue {
  background: #55C;
  min-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.red {
  background: #C55;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.yellow {
  background: #CC5;
  min-height: 100px;
}
  
/* flex for mobile */
@media(max-width: 700px) {
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .red, .yellow, .blue {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .yellow {
    order: 1;
  }
}

/* Not important.  Just here to make the demo look nicer */
section {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="red sidebar">red</section>
  <section class="yellow sidebar">yellow</section>
  <section class="blue">blue</section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Could this be a start for you?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.a {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}
.b {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}
.c {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .a {
    flex-basis: 50vh;
    width: 250px;
    order: 1;
  }
  .c {
    flex-basis: 50vh;
    width: 250px;
    order: 2;
  }  
  .b {
    flex-basis: 100vh;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">
  </div>
  <div class="b">
  </div>
  <div class="c">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up going with Joseph Marikle's answer, but I think this could have worked too, and it might help somebody in the future. Thank you! I upvoted your answer.